# Create input for open booking times?

Tags: javascript, laravel, date, laravel-blade, datetime-local

I am looking for ideas how to create and/or fill workday times in Laravel Blade.
At this moment I end up by:
[image: hardcoded input with values]

current code

```html
<input type="date" name="date">
<li class="list-group-item">
<input type="checkbox" name="time[]"  value="6">6:00
<input type="checkbox" name="time[]"  value="6:20">6:20
</li>
```

How to improve this using loops?

My goal is to create array with values

```
$times=["1" => "2021-08-20 6:00"],["2" => "2021-08-20 6:20"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define a `start` and `end` time along with a `duration` for each appointment.

```
$start = Carbon\Carbon::createFromTime(7, 0, 0, 'Europe/London');
$end = Carbon\Carbon::createFromTime(19, 0, 0, 'Europe/London');
$appointment_duration = 20;
```

Then use a loop to generate the timeslots between the `start` and `end`.

```
$appointments = [];

for ($appointment = $start;
     $appointment <= $end;
     $appointment->addMinutes($appointment_duration))  {
    
    $appointments[] = $appointment;

}
```

Once you have your `appointments` you can pass them to your view.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write your code like this

```
<input type="date" name="date">
<li class="list-group-item">
<input type="checkbox" name="time[1][]"  value="6">6:00
<input type="checkbox" name="time[2][]"  value="6:20">6:20
</li>
```

you will get code like this in controller

```
"time" => [
    1 => "6",
    2 => "6:20"

]
```